# wsimport with SOCKS proxy

Tags: java, proxy, jax-ws, socks, wsimport

We are developing a JAXWS client for a 3rd party WCF web service. The JAXWS client is going to be part of large web based application that would be deployed on tomcat. 
Not all servers in our env are allowed to communicate over the internet so out network team had configured a SOCKS proxy with authentication.

I know that I can pass -DsocksProxyHost as a command line parameter but I cannot do that since that applies for the entire web app. I've gone through this [javadoc-link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)

on how to setup connection based proxy settings.But the problem is , since I'm using the wsimport generated Service which abstracts the URL connection functionality, I'm not able to use the `URConnection conn = url.openConnection(proxy);` approach.

Any ideas/thoughts?

Comment: Do you want to communicate with WCF WS? Have you tried with `-httpproxy` and `-Xauthfile` options of `wsimport` of Java 6?

Comment: Yes, I've used like: wsimport http://hamlet:80/gisland/BDService?wsdl -keep -verbose -httpproxy:filesocks:1080 -d . -p com/agen/wpa/client/gen and I've the auth file in the my user_home/.metro folder

Comment: The generation of client is OK?

Comment: yes, the client is generated OK, no issues there.

Comment: Sorry the client didnt get generated: This is my ant target <target name="run_wsimport" depends="init">
  <exec executable="wsimport" failonerror="true">
   <arg line="http://hamtramck.cw.aa.com/Echoservice-D/Echoservice.svc?wsdl
      -d ${classes} -s ${app.src} -p com.ctxr.echo.gen 
      -wsdllocation  http://hamtramck.cw.aa.com/Echoservice-D/Echoservice.svc
      -keep -verbose -extension -httpproxy:bckhoust006.wcpa.com:1080" />
  </exec>
 </target>

Comment: And the output: run_wsimport: [exec] parsing WSDL...[exec] [INFO] Trying to read authorization file : "C:\Users\ravishch\.metro\auth"...[exec] [ERROR] Unexpected end of file from server [exec] Failed to read the WSDL document: http://hamtramck.cw.aa.com/Echoservice-D/Echoservice.svc?wsdl, because 1) could not find the document; /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <wsdl:definitions>. [exec] [ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s): ANY other ideas/thoughts? My n/w folks r saying they are doing this for PCI compliance